# Syntax error running command bc under bash 4.1

Tags: bash, scripting, bc

I have a bash script with the following line. The variables `start_time` and `start_files[$i]` are floating point numbers. I want to compare them using the command `bc` as follows:

```
result1=$(bc -l <<< $start_time'>='${start_files[$i]})
```

When I run the script I always receive the following error.

```
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
```

I've checked that this error is due to this line. What am I doing wrong? The thing that this happens to me when using bash 4.1, with bash 4.3 runs fine. However I need to run the script with bash 4.1.

The `bc` command works however the input doesn't work. The variable `start_files` is read from a file with this command

```
IFS=, read -r -a start_files <<< $(head -n 1 file.txt)
```

Basically I want to read all the values from the first line separated by a coma and store them to different positions of the array. However using bash 4.1 all the values end up stored in `start_files[0]`. How can I solve this? This lines works for bash 4.3

Comment: what are the values of those variables?

Comment: floating point values like 9.5, 4.2, 34.5678 etc

Comment: What do you see when you debug the script with `bash -x script`?  It often helps tell you what is wrong.  However, it does not print the here string, so you would have to modify the script to do `echo "bc -l <<< $start_time >= ${start_files[$i]}"` or something similar that accurately reflects what would be executed so as to see the input that `bc` is complaining about.  When solving a syntax error problem, the first thing you need to see is the syntax that is being complained about.

Comment: Sorry, I can not reproduce the error with bash version 4.1.2 (RHEL 6): `start_time=9.5; i=4; start_files[$i]=4.2; result1=$(bc -l <<< $start_time'>='${start_files[$i]}); echo $result1`

Comment: @KoTy, check that the *specific* values really are what you think they are -- a mistake leading to one of them being empty, f'rinstance, is a very likely cause of this error. Echo them out immediately before running `bc`; without doing so, since this is a `bc` syntax error rather than a bash syntax error, means we simply don't have enough information to help.

Comment: Please post more of the script. It's likely the syntax error is not where you think. Also, how are you running the script? The fact that the error is in standard_in, not a specific file, could be relevant.

Comment: The complaint remains. Previously, we could not guess what was in your variables; now, we cannot guess what's in your file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you use double quotes:

```
result1=$(bc -l <<<"$start_time >= ${start_files[$i]}")
```

This way, you are echoing a single string to `bc`, containing your variables.

Comment: keeps yielding me the same error, (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: Without knowing the values of the variables, it's impossible to say why. Perhaps you should use `set -x` so you can see what the values are that are causing your error.

Comment: @koty It must be the values: What does `echo ">>$start_time >= ${start_files[$i]}<<"` show you

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading the values from a file with DOS-style line endings perhaps?

```
$ start_time=$'1.5\r'
$ i=1
$ start_files[$i]=$'2.5\r'
$ bc -l <<< "$start_time >= ${start_files[$i]}"
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
```

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid the here-string, add double quotes and remove a `$`:

```
result1=$(echo "$start_time >= ${start_files[i]}" | bc -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to give the version of `bc` you're using. I'd guess it's not the same on the two systems. By the way, your error has nothing to do with Bash.

POSIX `bc` clearly states that a comparison (referred to as `relational_expression` in [POSIX' `bc` Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/bc.html) can only appear in a `while`, `for` or `if` construct.

So, first thing you'll try is this:

```
bc <<< "if($start_time >= ${start_files[$i]}) 1 else 0"
```

This might not work, as POSIX' `bc` *doesn't allow an `else` clause in an `if` statement*. (As amazing as it may seem, you read that last sentence correctly).

If your `bc` is really POSIX stuck up, then you'll have to do some ugly stuff as, e.g.,

```
bc <<< "ret=0; if($start_time >= ${start_files[$i]}) { ret=1 } ret"
```

or even something worse (sorry, I don't have a POSIX `bc` here, so I can't experiment—if someone has one at hand or remembers the syntax off the top of his head, please edit this line with the proper syntax).

Good luck!